# MS Access VBA always calling for Macro when manually running

Tags: ms-access, error-handling

Having this strange behaviour in my Access DB since today. If I try to run code in VBA (i.e. F5) a box comes up and asked to select a macro to run. Never had this problem before as I just want it to run the code I did. Tried to find a solution but no success.

I happens for all my code... like Public Function or Private Sub...

For example I created this code. When I execute it by clicking the button it works but if I run in VBA with F5 it always asks for the macro...

Public Sub Command18_Click()

MsgBox ("Hello")

End Sub

Comment: Is the procedure a Function?

Comment: Yes... I have things like functions Public Function or Private Sub... the strange thing is that this never happened before.

Comment: Nothing new. This happens when the function/sub is Private or in need of an argument.

Comment: Thanks @Gustav - but it's quite strange as this never happened before... I just did a test:

For example I created this code. When I execute it by clicking the button it works but if I run in VBA with F5 it always asks for the macro...

Public Sub Command18_Click()

MsgBox ("Hello")

End Sub

Comment: Then you never tried it with code behind form before. This will happen with any code behind form or report. Procedure can be Private in general module.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs if you try to hit f5 and run code in a form.

While you can hit f5 for a regular plain jane code in a code module, if you try this for form code, then f5 will pop that macro prompt.

Also, if by accident (or by intent) created a class module? Then again, you see that prompt.

So, for a form code module, or a class code module?

Such code can be started by hitting f5, since you need to create an "instance" of that class before it can be run.

And, a form's code module also is considered a class module - an instance (in this case the form has to be open) must be created first. So, in the case of form's code module, you can set break-point in that code to debug, but you can't hit f5 in such code modules, or inside of class modules - since an "instance" of that object has to be created first, and hitting f5 is not able nor capable of knowing which or even where such code exists to create the instance of that class code module (of which even form's code modules are also this case).

The HUGE giveaway here is that in your comments you note some click() event. Well, then that means your working with code inside of a form's code module - and f5 can't be used to start such code - it is still a class module, and an instance of that code module has to be created first.

So, if I create a class code module like this:

[image]

then

```
  Option Compare Database
  Option Explicit
  
  Sub TestMsg()
  
      MsgBox "hello"
  
  End Sub
```

Now, if I hit f5 in above sub, the macro prompt appears!!!!

I would have to create a plain jane regular code module, and say type in this:

```
Sub TestFun55()

  Dim MyClass As New Class1
  
  MyClass.TestMsg

        
End Sub
```

So, I can hit f5 in above.

And the SAME goes for code inside of a form's module. You can't hit f5 in that form's code module (which is considered a class code module).